# Does using a bonus action end One with Shadows?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, actions

The Warlock invocation One with Shadows grants invisibility until you "move or take an action or reaction." Does taking a bonus action end this invisibility?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it does, as a bonus action is an action on your turn, per PHB page 189.

Also [Crawford answered this question](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/09/20/does-using-a-bonus-action-break-invisibility/) specifically in [a pair](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/635833548902023168) [of tweets](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/635880453451333632), as well as clarified Bonus Actions:

> Yes, taking a bonus action breaks the invisibility of a warlock's One with Shadows. […] A bonus action is an additional action on your turn (PH, 189). Apart from its special rules, a bonus action is an action.