# Does a bonus action end invisibility gained from the Boon of the Night Spirit?

Tags: dnd-5e, invisibility, epic-tier

As the title says really. The Boon of the Night Spirit says:

> While completely in an area of dim light or darkness, you can become invisible as an action. You remain invisible until you take an action or a reaction. (DMG, Chapter 7, page 232)

If a character did something that they can do as a bonus action (certain spells, dash or disengage for a rogue, etc.), would the invisibility end?

Comment: Related: "[Does using a bonus action end One with Shadows?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89683)" and "[Do bonus actions trigger the save from an Internal Injury?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176472)" and "[Can you ready a bonus action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152204)" and "[Are actions and bonus actions interchangeable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111389)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PH189, under the **Bonus Action** subheading says (bold added for emphasis):

> Various class features, spells, and other abilities let you take **an additional action** on your turn called a bonus action.

Since a bonus action is an action, it would end the invisibility.

Comment: Identical wording to the Warlock's *One with Shadows.*