# Is One with Shadows eldritch invocation possible after certain bonus/free actions?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, rogue, invisibility, eldritch-invocations

I'm currently playing a Warlock/ Rogue multiclass character and I'm curious about the limitations of the One With Shadows invocation.

> ### One with Shadows
>
> *Prerequisite: 5th level*
>
> When you are in an area of dim light or darkness, you can use your
> action to become invisible until you move or take an action or a
> reaction.

The question is:

**Is it possible to take a movement, either a regular move or a cunning action and then use your action to become invisible (assuming the other conditions are met?)**

Certainly, movement (or any other bonus action) *after* becoming invisible is ***not*** allowed ([Because bonus actions are actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89683/does-using-a-bonus-action-end-one-with-shadows)) but it's unclear exactly what's allowed in a turn before using your official action to become invisible.

To me, all the 'cunning action' bonus actions would seem to be permitted, as long as I'm allowed a full action after any of them.

> ### Cunning Action
>
> Starting at 2nd level, your quick thinking and agility allow you to move and act quickly. You can take a bonus action on each of your turns in combat. This action can be used only to take the Dash, Disengage, or Hide action.

**So it seems to me you could do any of the following before taking an action to become invisible:**

- Dash
- Disengage & Move
- Move and hide

**Is this correct, or am I missing something in the action economy and/or order of actions, bonus actions, and movement?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It just says it's an action, so it's just an action

The invocation just says that you have to take an action while in dim light to become invisible. As such, any bonus actions or movement that you make before using that action, does not prevent the action from happening (unless stated otherwise). So, you can move, and if you use cunning action then yes, you can dash, disengage, or hide as well, before becoming invisible using this action, just as long as you end your turn in a place that is dark or dimly lit. You can also use any other bonus action during this time, including certain spells, etc. This ability does not restrict any of that.

Comment: Are you thinking of anything specific when you say "(unless stated otherwise)"? That is, is it stated otherwise or not?

Comment: nothing off the top of my head necessarily, but I wanted to leave the exception in because it's unlikely that there is not an exception, and even if there isn't, there may be in the future

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to say. I don't contest that a bonus action is an action, nor do I feel that anything I have said would go against that. Can you explain what you think is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

### You can move before or after your action

So, you can move some or all of your speed and then take your action to, in this case, become invisible.

### You can take a bonus action when the criteria are met

The criteria for Cunning Action is "on each of your turns in combat". So, if you are in combat and it's your turn you can do this and then take your action to, in this case, become invisible.

### You can take an Action anytime on your turn

### What can you do?

- Use your Cunning Action to Dash. This increases your Speed by an amount equal to your Speed (i.e. doubling it). You can then Move up to your (increased) Speed. Then use your Action to turn Invisible.
- Move up to your Speed. Use your Cunning Action to Disengage. Move with whatever Speed you have left without triggering Opportunity Attacks. Then use your Action to turn Invisible.
- Move up to your Speed. Use your Cunning Action to Hide. Move with whatever Speed you have left (which may cause you to "come out of hiding" or not). Then use your Action to turn Invisible.

And one more:-

- Move up to your Speed. Use your Action to turn Invisible. Because you are now unseen, use your Cunning Action to Hide which ends your Invisibility but you are now hidden. Move with whatever Speed you have left (which may cause you to "come out of hiding" or not).