# Does teleportation count as movement for the sake of One with Shadows invocation?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, invisibility, teleportation

The Eldritch Invocation, One with Shadows states

> When you are in an area of dim light or darkness, you can use your action to become invisible until you move or take an action or a reaction.

So does teleporting, such as that of a Misty Step spell, break the invisibility?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Invisibility is broken by bonus actions

There are three different triggers to break the invisibility provided by this feature. Those are listed as :

- Move
- Take an action
- Take a reaction

Bonus actions count as an additional action on your turn ([see this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89683/77044)), so it will trip the second trigger of the feature.

As such, as soon as you take your bonus action, you will break invisibility.

#### What about being moved by something else?

We've ruled out that casting the teleportation spell yourself breaks invisiblity, but what if you're teleported by another effect?

In the case where you do not use an action, bonus action or reaction, there is still the trigger of "move".

However, the term "move" directly refers to the movement you can do during your turn, which uses your speed. It is defined in the combat rules as such :

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed and take one action.

This is backed up by the wording of the feature itself, which features this term alongside the other actions one may take during their turn (emphasis mine) :

> When you are in an area of dim light or darkness, you can use your action to become invisible until you **move** or take an **action** or a **reaction**.

As such, as the rules are written, you can be moved by other effects, such as teleportation, without breaking invisibility.

Comment: Plain English: ***Has an object which had been moved, moved?*** You'll find the answer is yes. The intent seems to hold the warlock stationary. Whoever was the motor force for said movement seems irrelevant.

Comment: Move: "*To change position, location, or state*"
I was with you until we determined that "being moved = not moving" which I cannot make sense of. You could argue "until **you** move" being a point of concern, that it's not your intention to move, but any case where someone "moves you" your location has changed and you therefore, through no action of your own, move. The specific wording of Telekinesis for example states that "you **move** the creature" which would cause the creature to then move (even though it may not have wanted to).

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica except that this is  a game and not a novel. And it is well established that game terms can have quite distinct meanings and definitions from their original english. "to move" is such a game term: https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition. Moving in D&D is a precisely defined thing that a) uses speed (a concept completely contrary to it's English meaning) and b) is intentional  and c) on one's term. We can't rule out c) or b) but a) is a clear indicator

Comment: To make it even more clear, see this quote: (from the same link) "However you're moving, you deduct the distance of each part of your move from your speed until it is used up or until you are done moving." this almost directly says that anything that doesn't deduct from your speed is NOT moving as far as the rules are concerned.

Comment: @DangerLake just so you're mentioned as well. See my other two comments because you are making the same mistake as Mindwin. Telekinesis is a very weak counterexample because it uses the English "move" (because if would need to be spelled out if it were deducting from speed), but using this assumption for a list like "move or take an action or a reaction" is pretty far fetched imho

Comment: @Hobbamok The fact that "move" is a game term and does not have its normal English meaning is perhaps most clearly stated in the PHB errata: "Is standing up from prone considered moving? Standing up costs movement but moves you nowhere. When the game refers to you moving, it means moving some distance. It doesn’t mean making a gesture or standing up in place. To move while prone, you crawl or use magic"

Comment: I don't think it is reasonable to consider someone being moved around as "you are not moving" for the sake of this. The point seems that you stand (mostly) still and are invisible. Make one step and become visible. But get thrown around the room and still remain invisible? It doesn't make any logical sense to me.

Comment: @Hobbamok D&D 5e explicitly calls out that it is written in natural language. This type of reading isn't supported by the overall design of the game.

Comment: All points made by me are in support of the following:
**["being moved = not moving" is simply absurd.]** This is the point needing addressed at my table. 
In your point regarding standing from prone, it says clearly *"it means moving some distance."* which in the scenario described is occurring. 
It specifically gives the example "**To move** while prone, you crawl or **use magic**" in which magic is being used to Move someone. (Regardless if prone or standing) 
These suggest that moving any amount of distance, so long as you leave your current "square", you have moved.

Comment: @Habbomok You're definition of Move offered is misleading as this link is Specifically speaking about taking the move portion of your turn, certainly not "What is defined as moving or not moving." That it uses speed, for the purpose of how far you can willingly move, **not that only through speed can your position change.** That it's a willing action you make on your turn, rather than accidental, **not that enemies are unable to control you and make you move against your will.** That is happens on your turn, as part of your turn, **not that you must be considered unmoving on all other turns.**

Comment: "That it's a willing action you make on your turn" that us EXACTLY what I was getting at when I mentioned ""a list like "move or take an action or a reaction"". move is in this list, alongside two other active and deliberate activities.  You your bold text, if anything, is in support of my argument rather than against it

Comment: It seems you intentionally ignore the entire point I've made, that this is not Exclusionary. Your definitions refer to your ability to move in the context of what you can and can't do during your turn, that's it. Specifically it is NOT stating that movement can only occur on your turn. You can very much be moved by others and even be forced to move by others in the case of being shoved or spells such as Command which directly defeat the idea that moving must be a willful action and/or be made on your own turn. Each of my bold texts direct oppose and defeat your a) b) and c) mentioned above.

Comment: PHB189: "If you're surprised, you can't move or take an action on your first turn of the combat..."  If there is no rules distinction between moving and being moved, then clearly being surprised renders you immune to the forced movement of _thunderwave_, _thorn whip_, _etc._

Comment: I would argue that this again is in the context of available options for what you can do during your turn, not that it prevents movement from occurring on other (PC/Enemy) turns as you mention via thornwhip. All conditions affecting one's ability to move, don't actually mention the word "move" but that your speed becomes 0. Grapple even shows how we can remove the condition if something "removes" them from reach of the grappler. There is very little debate on what "removes" someone from reach vs was someone "removed" from that range. Tackling the earlier A) B) and C) will convince me though.